# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . error in below code? The console worked but my if statement is broken. Why?

```
var locations = $('myDiv');

console.log(locations.scrollTop(),locations.outerHeight())

if ( (locations.scrollTop()) => (locations.outerHeight()) ){ //error here
   alert('end');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Greater than or equal operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_or_equal_operator_(%3E)) is `>=` and not `=>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing syntactical error in Greater than or equal operator . Use the Correct syntax

```
var locations = $('myDiv');
console.log(locations.scrollTop(),locations.outerHeight())
if ( (locations.scrollTop()) >= (locations.outerHeight()) ){ 
   alert('end');
}
```